# How to extract an element from an HList with a specific (parameterized) type

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm chaining transformations, and I'd like to accumulate the result of each transformation so that it can potentially be used in any subsequent step, and also so that all the results are available at the end (mostly for debugging purposes). There are several steps and from time to time I need to add a new step or change the inputs for a step.

`HList` seems to offer a convenient way to collect the results in a flexible but still type-safe way. But I'd rather not complicate the actual steps by making them deal with the HList and the accompanying business.

Here's a simplified version of the combinator I'd like to write, which isn't working. The idea is that given an HList containing an A, and the index of A, and a function from A -> B, `mapNth` will extract the A, run the function, and cons the result onto the list. The resulting extended list captures the type of the new result, so several of these mapNth-ified steps can be composed to produce a list containing the result from each step:

```
def mapNth[L <: HList, A, B]
    (l: L, index: Nat, f: A => B)
    (implicit at: shapeless.ops.hlist.At[L, index.N]):
    B :: L =
  f(l(index)) :: l
```

Incidentally, I'll also need `map2Nth` taking two indices and `f: (A, B) => C`, but I believe the issues are the same.

However, `mapNth` does not compile, saying `l(index)` has type `at.Out`, but `f`'s argument should be `A`. That's correct, of course, so what I suppose I need is a way to provide evidence that `at.Out` is in fact `A` (or, `at.Out <: A`).

Is there a way to express that constraint? I believe it will have to take the form of an implicit, because of course the constraint can only be checked when `mapNth` is applied to a particular list and function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're exactly right about needing evidence that `at.Out` is `A`, and you can provide that evidence by including the value of the type member in `at`'s type:

```
def mapNth[L <: HList, A, B]
    (l: L, index: Nat, f: A => B)
    (implicit at: shapeless.ops.hlist.At[L, index.N] { type Out = A }):
    B :: L =
  f(l(index)) :: l
```

The companion objects for type classes like `At` in Shapeless also define an `Aux` type that includes the output type as a final type parameter.

```
def mapNth[L <: HList, A, B]
    (l: L, index: Nat, f: A => B)
    (implicit at: shapeless.ops.hlist.At.Aux[L, index.N, A]):
    B :: L =
  f(l(index)) :: l
```

This is pretty much equivalent but more idiomatic (and it looks a little nicer).

Comment: Thanks, that was definitely the missing piece.